# Form refresh after .submit() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am validating a form that's working fine but i don't know why the form not submit after all validations.

Here is validation code:

```
$('#coupon_options').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $('input[name="coupon_name"]'), 
        code = $('input[name="coupon_code"]'), 
        value = $('input[name="coupon_value"]'), 
        valid = $('input[name="coupon_valid"]'), 
        status = true;

    if( $.trim(name.val()) == "" ){
        name.css('border-color', '#ff0000');
        status = false;
    } else { name.removeAttr('style'); }

    if( $.trim(code.val()) == "" ){
        code.css('border-color', '#ff0000');
        status = false;
    } else { code.removeAttr('style'); }

    if( $.trim(value.val()) == "" ){
        value.css('border-color', '#ff0000');
        status = false;
    } else { value.removeAttr('style'); }

    if( $.trim(valid.val()) == "" ){
        valid.css('border-color', '#ff0000');
        status = false;
    } else { valid.removeAttr('style'); }

    if( status == true ){ return status; } 
    else { return false; }

});
```

As i know to stop the refresh after submit event i have used the `return false` but i am not sure return true works here or not?

I don't want to use Ajax, just want to submit after validation. 
Is there something wrong in this code??

Comment: post you html code , return false is generally used to prevent form submission

Comment: Try removing preventDefault()

Comment: @RajaM OHH man, now its working. Can anyone tell me here the purpose of `.preventDefault()`, like where we have to use this and why?

Comment: PreventDefault is used to cancel events caused due to bubbling

Comment: @jogesh_pi that was lucky guess which works for you....

Comment: @DipeshParmar that was not lucky :) I have experienced this kind of issues

Comment: @DipeshParmar yes absolutely right, i tried all my bests except this one ;)

Comment: @jogesh_pi well check for other error in firebug...because if you add `e.preventDefault()` it will over write browser default events so that means form posting will work only eventhandler that your attaching inside `.submit`

Comment: @jogesh_pi PreventDefault is used to disable the default action provided by browser which is in your case submitting the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove:

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

it stopping the default action to occur even you `return true;`.

For example:

- Prevent a submit button from submitting a form
- Prevent a link from following the URL

Comment: `it stopping the default action to occur` that means it will also stop the default form submitting....right..?

Comment: yes!!! it will. It use is where u dont want default action to occur and you want your code to execute.

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` is the issue, but you should note that it's never a good sign when you have multiple functions that basically perform the same action for different elements, you can simplify your code to this:

```
$('#coupon_options').submit(function(e){
    var status = true;
    $('input[name="coupon_name"],input[name="coupon_code"],input[name="coupon_value"],input[name="coupon_valid"]').each(function(){
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
            $(this).css('border-color', '#ff0000');
            status = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('style'); 
        }
    });
    return status;
});
```

And you could even use `$('input[name^="coupon_"]')` to select all inputs that start with that prefix.

Comment: @jogesh_pi it's not a trick, you should learn [all the different selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that jQuery offers, also you can reduce your code even more and have it all in one line like this http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/8s8p2/